# Subdividing and counting how many values in particular columns under certain conditions in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am new to R and data analysis. I have a database similar to this one below, just a lot bigger and I was trying to find a general way to count for each country how many actions there are and how many subquestion with value 1, value 2 and so on there are. For each action there are multiple questions, subquestions and subsubquestions but I would love to find a way to count

1:how many actions there are per country, excluding subquestions

2: a way to find out how many subquestions 1 or 2 with value 1 there are for each country, actionn and questionn.

```
id country questionn subquestion value      actionn
06  NIE       1          1        1           1
05  NIG       1          1        1           1
07  TAN       1          1        1           1
08  BEN       1          1        1           1
03  TOG       1          1        2           1
45  MOZ       1          1        2           1
40  ZIM       1          1        1           1
56  COD       1          1        1           1
87  BFA       1          1        1           1
09  IVC       1          1        2           1
08  SOA       1          1        2           1
02  MAL       1          1        2           1
78  MAI       1          1        2           1
35  GUB       1          1        2           1
87  RWA       1          1        2           1
41  ETH       1          1        1           1
06  NIE       1          2        2           1
05  NIG       1          2        1           1
87  BFA       1          2        1           2
```

I have tried to create subsets of the data frame and count everything for each country once at a time but it is going to take forever and I was wondering if there was a general way to do it. 
For the first question I have done this

```
df1<-df %>% group_by (country) %>% summarise (countries=county)

unique(df1)
count(df1)
```

For the second question I was thinking of individually select and count each rows which has quesionn=1, subquestion=1, value=1 and actionn=1, then to select and count how many per country with qustionn=1, subquestionn=2, value=1, actionn=1 etc. Value refers to whether the answer to the question is 1=yes or 2=no.

I would be grateful for any help, thank you soo much :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can try to do something like this:

`df %>% 
  filter(subquestion != 2) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(num_actions = n())`

This will return the number of actions per country, removing rows that do not have 2 for the subquestion column. Note that the `n()` in the `summarize` function will count the number observations in the groups (in this case countries).

I am not sure I fully understand the second question, but my suggestion would be to make a new label for the particular observation you want to know (how many subquestions 1 or 2 with value 1 there are for each country, actionn and questionn):

`df %>%
  mutate(country_question_code = paste(country, action, questionn, sep = "_")) %>%
  group_by(country_question_code) %>%
  summarize(num_subquestion = n())`

Answer (score 0):

For question 1 possible solution (assuming country name are not unique and actionn can be 0, 1,2 or more..
For just total count:

`df%>%group_by(country)%>%
summarise(
"Count_actions" = sum(actionn)
) #ignores all other columns.`

If you want to count how many times a country appears use `n()` in place of `sum(actionn, na.rm=TRUE)`.# this may not be desired but sometime simple solution is the best
 (Just count the frequency of country)

Or  `df%>%group_by(country, actionn)%>%summarise("count_actions"= n())` will give country wise count for each type ( say 1,2 or more actions).

Data table version `dt[, .(.N), by=.(country, actionn )]`

For question 2: use grouping for "for each on your question" after putting filter on data as required. Here, filter subquestions 1 or 2 with (and) value 1 for each "country, question and actionn":

`df%>%filter(subquestions <=2 & value==1)%>%group_by( country, question, actionn)%>%summarise("counts_desired"= n(), "sums_desired"= sum(actionn, na.rm=TRUE))`

Hope this works. I am also learning and applying it on similar data. 
Have not tested it and made certain assumptions about your data (numerical and clean). (Also for.mobile while traveling! Cheers!!)

Comment: @user394323 : could you find a solution or checked if this is working? I